# show Save-Button when items added

Tags: reactjs

I would like the save button to appear only when an item is added and when all items are deleted or saved, the button is set to hide.....

Could you tell me how should I implement?

The second question would be how should I programming the save button

[image]

Shopping-List Component:

```
export default function ShoppingList () {
    // Enthält alle values die aus dem Input Element hinzugefügt wurden
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    // Enthält value aus dem Element Input
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const AddButtonClick = () => {
        if (inputValue === ""){
            alert("Eingabefeld ist Leer");
        } else {
            // Wird das neue Array zurück in den status gepusht
            setItems(prevState => [...prevState, inputValue]);
            // Setzt den inputValue auf eine leere Zeichenkette zurück
            setInputValue('');
        }
    }


    const deleteButtonClick = (index) => {
        const newItems = items && items.filter((element , i) => i !== index);
        setItems(newItems);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div className="error">
                <Alert
                    message="Error"
                    description="Eingabefeld ist Leer!"
                    type="error"
                    showIcon
                />
            </div>
            <div className="eingabe">
                <Input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
                       name='input'
                       className='addItemInput'
                       placeholder="Artikel hinzufügen"
                />
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    onClick={() => AddButtonClick()}
                >Add</Button>
            </div>
            <div className='itemList'>
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <ul className='itemContainer'>
                        <li className='item-name'>
                            {item}
                        </li>
                        <div className='delete-btn'>
                            <Button type="primary" danger onClick={() => deleteButtonClick(index)}>
                                Delete
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                ))}
                <div className="speichernBtn">
                    <Button
                        type="primary"
                    >Save
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [conditional rendering](https://reactpatterns.com/#conditional-rendering) to make this work.
This for example will only render the button if there are items in the list.

*Please see the edit below for an improved version*

```js
{items.length !== 0 && (
    <div className="speichernBtn">
      <Button type="primary">Save</Button>
    </div>
)}
```

The condition could of course be more complex if needed.
Another way would be to hide the button using some CSS to set the [`display`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property.

Many component libraries also have props to do this kind of thing i.e. applying CSS to a component. You have not mentioned which component library you are using but if you were to use Material UI you could use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop) to do this.

```js
<div className="speichernBtn">
  <Button 
    type="primary" 
    sx={{ display: items.length !== 0 ? "inline-block": "none" }}>
    Save
  </Button>
</div>;
```

When using [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com/) you could just use the `display` prop directly. But you would need to check out the documentation of your component library to see how this can be done.

### Edit

As [mrpbennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10129053/mrpbennett) pointed out you should use a ternary operator instead of `&&` to make sure nothing is rendered otherwise `0` could be rendered. Here a link to a [blog article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-ternaries-rather-than-and-and-in-jsx) explaining this in more depth as provided by [mrpbennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10129053/mrpbennett).

So this would be the code following this advise.

```js
{items.length !== 0 ? (
    <div className="speichernBtn">
      <Button type="primary">Save</Button>
    </div>
  ) : null}
```

Comment: although this is correct this would be the better way to implement it. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-ternaries-rather-than-and-and-in-jsx

Comment: Thanks @mrpbennett. I've added an improved version of my answer to reflect that. With attribution of course :)

Comment: I meant the save button and not delete button. How should I actually turn the save button on or off?

Comment: My bad. Corrected the answer. It's still the same idea though, you just need to enter the elements you want to render in the `( )` after the condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, because personally I am not a big fan of the inline ternary.

add the following method:

```
const isItemsEmpty() => {
  return items.length > 0
}
```

Then for the button element use the following:

```
<Button
  type="primary"
  danger
  onClick={() => deleteButtonClick(index)}
  hidden={isItemsEmpty()}
  disabled={isItemsEmpty()}
>
Delete
</Button>
```

Comment: I meant the save button and not delete button. How should I actually turn the save button on or off?

Comment: Same exact thing but add the hidden and disabled props to the save button instead of the delete button.

Answer (score -1):

How I would approach this is first I would create a constant that tells you if you should show your button or not:

```
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);
```

After this, you should check if showButton is true in all places where you only want to show your button if that variable is true. For example, you would do something like this:

```
{showButton && 
<Button type="primary" onClick={() => AddButtonClick()}>
    Add
</Button>}
```

Then you would need to modify the state in all functions that are called when you need to show the button:

```
const deleteButtonClick = (index) => {
        const newItems = items && items.filter((element , i) => i !== index);
        setItems(newItems);
        showButton(true);
    }
```

And do the opposite when you don't want it to be shown, for example:

```
function handleSave(){
    showButton(false);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a bit overcomplicated, the boolean state does not to be stored because we can always check if items.length > 0.

Comment: If I were to do it with state, I would also take advantage of the useEffect hook to check the length and update the state, instead of relying on other developers to know that they have to manually show and hide the button if they need to do this for any other reason in the component.

Comment: I meant the save button and not delete button. How should I actually turn the save button on or off?